# Oracle SQL Developer insert and delete buttons disabled

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer for my Oracle DB, wonder why are my shortcut buttons are being disabled (see attached image) while the user acc i logged in has the permission to add/edit/delete rows. I am able to add rows by typing in query. How should I enable them?
And also not able to edit the row using the GUI by clicking on the pencil button.

[image]

Comment: I think that if you selected rowid, these buttons would be active. For example `select t.rowid, t.* from yourTable t`

Comment: Which SQL Developer version do you use? If it is not the latest (currently, 17.4), try to upgrade. Because, I'm trying to simulate what you described and can't succeed. The DELETE button is *dimmed* when no rows are selected, but the INSERT button is always here.

Comment: the version i installed is 17.4

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I am seeing the same exact thing. I noticed this starting with 17.4.0 and am now on 17.4.1 and same thing.  The really bizarre thing is that not all database connections exhibit this behavior which is beyond me.

Comment: unfortunately no. no idea. appreciate you to share with me if you found the reason. :)